# Node.JS Debugging Node Inspector not single stepping?

Tags: node.js

Node inspector installs and loads fine on a clean system - code breaks at breakpoints, but when I try to single step (either F10 or hit the button) or try to continue execution, it just hangs.   Has anyone seen this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem since moving to 0.10.0 and now to 0.10.1. It is not node-inspector because WebStorm exhibits a similar problem. It does not pick up breakpoints in my code and if I use the debugger command it will break and show me the file in red (with line number), but not load it - even though it show the correct path on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Node 0.10.1 but breakpoints in node-inspector had worked fine previously (before hard drive crash). **I reverted to Node 0.8.22 and the problem was fixed.** I installed Node with Homebrew, so to revert node I did (use the version hash you desire):

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ brew versions node
$ git checkout 3c4a714 Library/Formula/node.rb
$ brew unlink node
$ brew install node
$ git checkout HEAD -- Library/Formula/node.rb
$ brew switch node 0.8.22
```